# How to correctly implement cyclic arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on a tiny piece of JavaScript to make a page background image cycle through an array of pictures with a button press.

However, the array doesn't cycle back to the beginning once the user reaches the last picture.

I'm not entirely sure what happened, but the problem arose when I implemented session storage to make the background images persist across page reloads and loads.

The code I used is as such:

```
var bodyObj, imgSrc, index;

bodyObj = document.getElementById('bgChange'); // For the button used to trigger the image change)

index = 0;

imgSrc = ['', 'jill.gif', 'shimmer.gif', 'lightpollution.gif', 'crystal.gif', 'rain.gif', 'puke.gif', 'town.gif']; // The array of pictures

maxIndex = Object.keys(imgSrc).length;

function updateIndex() { // The cyclic array
    index += 1;
    if (index > maxIndex) {
        index = 0;
    }
    sessionStorage.clear(); // Session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('img', JSON.stringify(imgSrc[index]))
}

window.onload = function() { // Session storage
    main.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('img')) + '")';
    main.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
};

bodyObj.onclick = function() { // Trigger background image change on button press
    main.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('img')) + '")';
    main.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    updateIndex();
}
```

Comment: You probably want `index >= maxIndex` since JavaScript arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your updateIndex function, use `if(index > maxIndex - 1)`
Since array index starts from 0. if your length is 5 then the index ends at 4

Comment: Or `index >= maxIndex` as @Pointy wrote in the comment to the question.

Comment: Yeah, Didn't see your comment

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author).*

Damn, now I feel even dumber. I remember Ctrl+Zing my way through the code multiple times when I was trying to figure out session storage so that's probably how I managed to pull something this stupid off. Thanks, pointy and doc.